# pep8 compliant is so confusing me right now

Tags: python, pep8

```
from lab10 import Card
from lab10 import ChipBank
import random

# returns string 

class BlackjackHand(list): 

    def __str__(self):
        hand = ' '
        for item in self:
            x = item.get_suit()
            y = item.get_rank()
            hand += (str(y) + " of " + str(x) \
                     + ',')
        return hand
```

- This is not my full code,but i have got pep8 error which says line is too long(5340 > 79)
- it starts at 1:80
- but my first would end after import random.. please help?

Comment: I really can't tell what you're asking with that error and that code.

Comment: What's the actual error you get? Copy-paste the exact message and edit it into your question. Also, the error message is pretty clear, it thinks you have a line that's 5340 chars long. Do you have any really long lines?

Comment: It thinks it have 5340 chars. I don't have any big lines. I also went through all of the line delete white spaces at the each lines! It also say i need white space after ':' after all of my function and methods

Comment: If you want help with a second problem, you should open a second question, but please be accurate—copy and paste the actual message instead of trying to describe it. (You _could_ be talking about the message you get from `def foo():return 3`, but if so, the fix is pretty obvious. Put a space there.)

Comment: well when i put space after ':' it says unexpected white space after ':' but i will open up new question with my full code

Comment: Could you try to read your script into a string a print repr() of that string?

Answer (score 2):

The are two possibilities here.

- You might have a whole slew of blank spaces after the end of the line. Being spaces, they're invisible to you as a reader, but being characters, they're visible to the `pep8` tool.
- You might have mixed Windows-style (`\r\n`) and Unix-style (`\n`) line endings. If the first line ends with `\r\n`, but a bunch of other lines end with `\n`, `pep8` will assume they're all one big line. Python itself *may* guess what you want and let you get away with it, but you should still fix it.

If your text editor doesn't have any way to show you trailing spaces and newline characters, you may want to get a better one. But meanwhile, you can write a Python script to clean your Python script…